# How to add filter to Get query to swagger?

Tags: java, rest, swagger, filtering

I want to add query filter to my GET/Users endpoint in order to filter my request in swagger by username. I've created a class name "Filter" with only one field - "private String username".
My controller looks like this:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Success"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Client error"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Server error")
})
@GetMapping("/Users")
public ResponseEntity<PagingDto<UserResource>> getUsers(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                        @Min(1)
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Integer startIndex,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Integer count,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Filter filter) {
    final PagingDto<UserResource> users = userService.getUsers(startIndex, count);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Additionally, my filter has Integer maxResult and Boolean suppoted but unfortunately, it doesn't work.
My method "getUsers" looks like:

```
@Override
public PagingDto<UserResource> getUsers(Integer startIndex, Integer count) {
    final PagingDto<UserResource> users = get(startIndex, count);
    return users;
}
```

Previously, I've tried to add to parameters "Filter filter" but it hadn't help either. I see the field "filter" in query section in swagger but it doesn't work properly.
Can you help me please to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping("/Users")
public ResponseEntity<PagingDto<UserResource>> getUsers(
    @RequestParam(required = false) Integer count,
    @ParameterObject Filter filter) {
    ...
    
public class Filter {
    @Parameter(description="optional description")
    String username;
    // accessors
}
```

This should result in HTTP request with parameters:
/Users?count=1&username=aaa

You can move all your parameters to Filter class.

```
@GetMapping("/Users")
public ResponseEntity<PagingDto<UserResource>> getUsers(
    @ParameterObject Filter filter) {
    ...
    
public class Filter {
    Integer count;

    @Parameter(description="optional description")
    String username;
    // accessors
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But unfortunately id didn't help because I still cannot filter my request by username. But I can filter my request as previous by startIndex and count field. Are there any other possible solution for this?

Comment: You should be more specific by what "still cannot filter my request by username" exactly means. First of all, check if Spring MVC parameter is working as intended without swagger, e.g. send `/Users?count=1&username=aaa` request via browser or curl, postman etc. and check if filter.username variable is populated. Don't forget accessors. As for swagger, add @ParameterObject annotation to Filter controller parameter. This should make Filter properties (username) visible in swagger-ui. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I' ve added accessors and @ParameterObject! 
When I wrote about error I meant that I've added some username in filter field in swagger but it hadn't filter my users and showed the list of all users. And in postman it didn't work too.

Comment: Well, the question is labeled "How to add filter to Get query to swagger?" and I am giving my answer to that question. Obviously, we don't see what you're doing with filter object in your code and why it doesn't work as you expect. In your original message filter object is not used at all as you're not passing it to userService. If you do see "username" parameter in swagger-ui and filter object in your controller gets its "username" property populated correctly (as you should check by debugging or printing, etc), I think your swagger-related question is answered.